# Drawing parallel lines with a turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to write a function that makes parallel lines in turtle and takes the following four parameters:

- a turtle
- length, that is the length of each line
- reps, that is the number of lines to draw
- separation, that is the distance between parallel lines

so far I've got this:

```
import turtle as t

def parallelLines(length, reps, separation):
    t.fd(length)

    t.penup()

    t.goto(0, separation)

    for i in reps:
         return i
```

Comment: Okay, can you think about how you’d do it in real life? Ignore Python for a moment.

Comment: And how would you do it as a turtle, since your lines are perfectly straight and your turns are perfectly accurate?

Comment: Draw the first line X length, then move down from the beginning of that first line Y length and repeat until I have however many reps I need

Comment: Sure. So can you translate that to Python?

Comment: You should go through a Python tutorial, asking questions on stackoverflow is not a substitute for learning how to program.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to draw a dashed line is to increase the length by changing the range value

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

t = Turtle()

for i in range(15):

    t.forward(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(10)
    t.pendown()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This answer ignores the OP's stated parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far are all incomplete, incorrect and/or broken. I've one below that uses the stated API and draws parallel lines.

The OP didn't make clear where the lines should appear relative to the turtle's position so I went with the turtle being at the center point in both dimensions:

```
import turtle

STAMP_SIZE = 20

def parallelLines(my_turtle, length, reps, separation):
    separation += 1  # consider how separation 1 & 0 differ

    my_stamp = my_turtle.clone()
    my_stamp.shape('square')
    my_stamp.shapesize(1 / STAMP_SIZE, length / STAMP_SIZE, 0)
    my_stamp.tilt(-90)
    my_stamp.penup()
    my_stamp.left(90)
    my_stamp.backward((reps - 1) * separation / 2)

    for _ in range(reps):
        my_stamp.stamp()
        my_stamp.forward(separation)

    my_stamp.hideturtle()

turtle.pencolor('navy')

parallelLines(turtle.getturtle(), 250, 15, 25)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question:

> Draw the first line X length, then move down from the beginning of
>   that first line Y length and repeat until I have however many reps I
>   need

This translated into code would look like:

```
goto start position
for _ in reps:
    pen down
    move length to the right
    pen up
    move length to the left
    move separation to the bottom
```

Now you just need to fill in the correct calls to your turtle-API.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead:

```
def parallel():
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.forward(distanceyouwantbetweenthem)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
```

Comment: This answer ignores the OP's stated parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this

```
def lines(length, sep, reps):
    for _ in range(reps-1):
        fd(length)
        bk(length)
        penup()
        lt(90)
        fd(sep)
        rt(90)
        pendown()
    fd(length)
    bk(length) 
lines(length, sep, reps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :)

```py
import turtle as t

tix = t.Turtle()

for _ in range(15):
    tix.forward(10)
    tix.penup()  #Pull the pen up – no drawing when moving.
    tix.forward(10)
    tix.pendown()  #Pull the pen down – drawing when moving.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).